# Can apache servers from two different server locations share the same ssl/http certificate?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, domain, apache2

I have two Apache servers on two different locations as illustrated in the following situation:

## Server 1

- On GoDaddy or other affordable-solution provider
- IP 172.56.98.19
- www.yum.com

## Server 2

- On AWS LightSail
- IP 170.76.90.12
- backoffice.yum.com
- Note this is a different apache server.

## Questions:

1. Can I register the second server as a sub domain (backoffice) of the first server?
2. If I can, can I purchase an SSL certificate that would work for both?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a wildcard cert or a multi-domain cert for both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can purchase one certificate that will work for both servers. A wildcard certificate would work perfectly for this. You can get an affordable one at ssl.com for around $225 USD:
https://www.ssl.com/ssl-wildcard-certificates/

But there are tons of other providers, so shop around.

You would need to register a DNS entry for backoffice.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you can run the same certificate on an indefinite number of servers. The goal is to do it correctly to avoid certificate errors. The best practice in this place would be to purchase one certificate which contains both domains in the the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) field. This would allow both servers to utilize the same certificate without certificate errors.